# Create a new column in Dataframe based on condition being check. I want to check value of a column for multiple values and then assign it a value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is what I am doing now:

```
df1.loc[df1['Product'] == "Bat",'Category'] = "Sports"
df1.loc[df1['Product'] == "Medicine",'Category'] = "Pharma"
df1.loc[df1['Product'] == "shoes",'Category'] = "Fashion"
```

But now I need to perform the check for other stuff also using the same line i.e like a ball, clothes, etc

```
df1.loc[df1['Product'] == ["Bat" or "Ball"],'Category'] = "Sports"
```

While doing this getting below error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there any better way for the same, I want to perform the check on a large number of products?

Comment: `df1['Product'].isin(['Bat', 'Ball'])`.

Comment: and also consider `np.select` for multiple conditions. Also `map` would work pretty well.